# Polynomial fitting with log log plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

I have a simple problem to fit a straight line on log-log scale. My code is,

```
data=loadtxt(filename)
xdata=data[:,0]
ydata=data[:,1]
polycoeffs = scipy.polyfit(xdata, ydata, 1)
yfit = scipy.polyval(polycoeffs, xdata)
pylab.plot(xdata, ydata, 'k.')
pylab.plot(xdata, yfit, 'r-')
```

Now I need to plot fit line on log scale so I just change x and y axis,

```
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xscale('log')
```

then its not plotting correct fit line. So how can I change fit function (in log scale) so that it can plot fit line on log-log scale?

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. Are your ranges including the zero? In this case you cannot plot in log scale. Try to modify the ranges of the axes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

```
from scipy import polyfit
data = loadtxt("data.txt")
xdata,ydata = data[:,0],data[:,1]
xdata,ydata = zip(*sorted(zip(xdata,ydata))) # sorts the two lists after the xdata    

xd,yd = log10(xdata),log10(ydata)
polycoef = polyfit(xd, yd, 1)
yfit = 10**( polycoef[0]*xd+polycoef[1] )

plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(xdata,ydata,'.k',xdata,yfit,'-r')
plt.subplot(212)
plt.loglog(xdata,ydata,'.k',xdata,yfit,'-r')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes. I tried that option too but fit line is not different. Still problem there.

Comment: It may be because you fit with a linear fit `polyval(xdata,ydata,1)`. How does the theoretical fit looks like? And does it even looks okay in an ordinary `plt.plot(...)`

Comment: Yes it is very well correlated. If I take log of data before plotting (xdata=log10[data:,0],xdata=log10[data:,1]), then it fit proper.

Comment: Can you upload the data somewhere?

Comment: xdata= [2.55845319601,3.42711901085,5.3426745947,3.6095268123,4.2562007078,4.74551478941,4.74924625755,3.79708949677,3.91314611276,4.78042443192,2.93958035272,3.2102798029,3.78540075621,4.79463055418,3.26432292903,2.53434657812,4.17502180186,3.8845072931,2.5459527268,2.93449693734,2.80126746798,4.03149023239,4.59230662026,3.05859058784,6.6980093253,4.23015139045,4.24947012686,6.25955209328,6.04066595196,4.71369938479,3.88714628311,3.54209919333,3.26209216123,2.54650573646,2.21561145226,2.1101195414,2.27520552298,2.8226227057,1.80334547413,1.743133602,3.58106715145,3.07269650714,2.70146456011]

Comment: ydata=[2.13,0.6,0.31,0.47,0.51,0.43,0.61,1.68,0.51,0.41,2.36,8.22,0.86,0.47,0.7,1.18,0.37,3.63,3.62,2.68,12.46,1.25,0.88,10.99,0.42,0.47,1.53,0.59,0.25,0.53,1.94,5.15,8.81,1.69,17.04,7.62,14.03,0.84,16.59,12.66,1.34,1.0,6.14]

Comment: Okay, I've tried to fit it now. The proble is that you are trying to fit with a linear fit with something that is only linear in a loglog scale. See my edited answer for how I did a loglog plot and so on

Comment: One more thing I want to evaluate is, if my xdata are all negative values then how can I perform above fitting? I tried with 'symlog' but its not plotting the straight line. Do you know how to change linear fit function for symlog?

Comment: Sorry no, I've never tried that. Unless there is a meaning with negative x-values I would probably just shift it, so the minimum x-value is positive.

Comment: If mine solutions is good enough, please accept it. It is the Stackoverflow way to give some credits :)

Comment: If I just shift my negative value to positive then it will make my slope negative (just reverse) also it will plot on other way data points and fit line.

Answer (score 1):

you want

`log(y) = k log(x) + q`, so

`y = exp(k log(x) + q) = exp(k log(x)) * exp(q) = exp(log(x^k)) * exp(q) = A x^k`

as you can see one requirement is `y(0) = 0`.

From the code point of view, you are plotting the fit function using only the x of the data, probably it is better to add points:

```
xfit = scipy.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata), 50)
yfit = scipy.polyval(polycoeffs, xfit)
ax.plot(xfit, yfit, 'r-')
```

Comment: if my xdata are all negative values then how can I perform above fitting? I tried with 'symlog' but its not plotting the straight line. Do you know how to change linear fit function for symlog?

Comment: what's the problem about negative value? The problem is if you intersect the zero