# Linear fit with log plot including errors on the y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was following this discussion: [Polynomial fitting with log log plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623571/polynomial-fitting-with-log-log-plot)
to linearly fit data on a log axis. However, I still can not understand how to include the errors (in my case, on the y data) in the fit and in the plot. Any suggestion please?

EDIT: the log axis is only the x axis

Comment: what do your data look like? what form are they in? do you have some examples of a final result you'd like to see?

Comment: have you tried `plt.errorbar` ?

Comment: Example of data:
x = [690, 530, 438, 408, 283, 160, 105, 15, 3.6, 4.4, 4.8]
y = [19,  14,  10,  21,  17,  4,   17,  22, 19,  6,   30]
yerr=[3,  4,   6,   5,   8,  9,   4,   2,  2,   1,   5]

How can I use errorbar with log axis?